# Loop thru multiple workbook then match cell value if found then update different cell in active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Every body.
I have active sheet open (OPEN Media Consolidation). I want to pick a value from C column then go thru each workbook and within each workbook there are many sheets. If that value ( value from C column form active sheet) matches anywhere in that workbook in any sheet then I want to update in active sheet H column saying found otherwise no update. I was going thru below script but not able to loop thru each sheet/each column in other two workbooks. any idea very much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Found()
Dim NumberOfValues1 As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook
Dim wbsb1 As Worksheet
Dim newExcel As Excel.Application
Set newExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\anil\avamar list\DSM_Master_Full Tapes.xlsx")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\anil\avamar list\DSM_Master_Incremental.xlsx")
    
NumberOfValues1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPEN Media Consolidation").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Set wbsb1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPEN Media Consolidation")
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 2 To NumberOfValues1
            
            For Each Worksheet In wb1
                'how to compare LCase(wbsb1.Range("A" & i).Value) to each cell value
                'if found then update wbsb1.Range("H" & i).Value = "Found"
                
                
            Next
            
            For Each Worksheet In wb2
            'how to compare LCase(wbsb1.Range("A" & i).Value) to each cell value
                'if found then update wbsb1.Range("H" & i).Value = "Found"
            Next

Next
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 wb.Close
    newExcel.Quit
    Set newExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Using [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) maybe?

Comment: can you direct me how to use find ?

Comment: " I want to pick a value from C column", your code comment `how to compare LCase(wbsb1.Range("A" & i).Value)` says column A

Comment: sorry it should be LCase(wbsb1.Range("C" & i).Value)  .

Comment: @Postmaster: I literally linked to the documentation for it

Answer (score 0):

will below code can do trick ?

```
    Option Explicit
Sub Found()
Dim NumberOfValues1, NumberOfValues2, NumberOfValues3 As Integer
Dim i, n, o As Long
Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook
Dim wbsb1, worksheet1, worksheet2 As Worksheet
Dim newExcel As Excel.Application
Set newExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim value1, value2, value3 As String
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\anil\commvault\DSM_Master_Full Tapes.xlsx")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\anil\commvault\DSM_Master_Incremental.xlsx")
    
    
NumberOfValues1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPEN Media Consolidation").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Set wbsb1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPEN Media Consolidation")
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 2 To NumberOfValues1
          value1 = wbsb1.Range("C" & i).Value
           For Each worksheet1 In wb1.Worksheets
                NumberOfValues2 = worksheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
                 For n = 1 To NumberOfValues2
                  value2 = worksheet1.Cells(n, 1)
                     If value1 = value2 Then
                      wbsb1.Range("o" & i).Value = "Found"
                     End If
                 Next
            Next
            
            For Each worksheet2 In wb2.Worksheets
                NumberOfValues3 = worksheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
                 For o = 1 To NumberOfValues3
                  value3 = worksheet2.Cells(o, 1)
                     If value1 = value3 Then
                      wbsb1.Range("o" & i).Value = "Found"
                     End If
                 Next
            Next
        

Next
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 wb1.Close
  wb2.Close
    newExcel.Quit
    Set newExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: above code works with small number of rows. But It runs forever if active sheet "OPEN Media Consolidation" has 96000 rows and "DSM master full tapes" has 4000 rows and "dsm master incremental" has 2000. Any idea what i am missing ??

Comment: Actually active sheet "OPEN Media Consolidation" has 96000 rows and "DSM master full tapes" workbook has 44000 rows in different sheets and "dsm master incremental" workbook has 22000 in different sheets. Any idea what i am missing ??

Comment: HELLO Anybody can help why my code is hanging not completing ??

Answer (score 0):

From the code in your answer post you have a triple nested `For` loop with no exit conditions. This is why it takes forever to run on larger datasets.

Are you looking for the first occurrence of that value per sheet or are you looking for **all** the values per sheet?

Have a look at the below code and see if you can get it working for what you need. I have not done the second nested `For` loop.

```
For Each worksheet1 In wb1.Worksheets
    NumberOfValues2 = worksheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
                
    On Error Resume Next

    'Look for value1 in Range C:C in worksheet1
    value2 = worksheet1.Range("C1:C" & NumberOfValues2).Find(value1)
    If Err.Number <> 91 Then 'If the value was found
        wbsb1.Range("O" & i).Value = "Found"
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    'If the value was not found, move on to the next worksheet

Next

'Add the Code for your wb2.Worksheets loop
```